# Unable to get the Filtered Values when passing the parameter into filter Value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have multi Valued Parameter which have list of values in the Drop down .

I am trying to apply filter on the data set.My requirement is when i choose a value from Drop down,it should be filtered on that value.

I am using the below value in my DATA SET Filters

```
 =join(Parameters!TierStatus.Value,",")
```

But i am getting an Error like

"Failed to evaluate the FilterValues of the Dataset"

How can write a filter expression based on the multi valued parameter

Comment: What are you using for the rest of the elements of the filter?   Are you using "IN" for the operator?

Comment: Yes I tried with "In" too

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "IN" as the operator, you should be able to simply put your parameter in the Value field (do not use the JOIN function).

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c02370b5-aeda-47ec-a3a8-43b2ec1e6c26/reporting-services-multi-value-parameter

Comment: I tried with Simply putting the parameter without join , But it is not taking the multiple values

Comment: You need to show more of what you are doing and what is happening then, because according to the article I referenced, that is the solution that should work.